# Not getting saved SharedPreference value from IntentService

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm creating a shared preference in my MainActivity and then I want to get a value saved in the shared preference in my IntentService; however; I keep getting the default value rather than the value that I had saved.

This is my code to create the SharedPreference in my MainActivity:

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  prefs.edit().putString("inter", inter).apply();
```

And in my IntentService class:

```
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
  SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String inter = preferences.getString("inter", "default_no");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is a subtle one:

[SharedPreferences.Editor#commit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) stores the modifications to storage in a blocking fashion, so you are guaranteed that any other instance that queries the value *on the same thread* will actually get the new one.

[SharedPreferences.Editor#apply](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) does so asynchronously so if you fetch the value on *another* instance of SharedPreferences too fast, it might not get the updated value.

Commit may actually work better on your situation as you are not doing any big change to the preferences. If you need to use apply, you might want to induce a slight delay using [Handler#post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)).

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using and editor to save your value in SharedPreferences

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editoreditor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("inter", inter);
    editor.commit();//This will make your value store in SharedPreferences
```